# How to plot a graph showing a score for each line in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How to plot this kind of graph ?[image: graph showing a score for each line]

(Here is [the source](https://venngage.com/blog/survey-results/))

Considering that I have this :

Option A:

- Person I : 0
- Person J : 2
- Person K : 4

The score goes from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very clear regarding what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you interested in the formatting of the chart?  The data layout required? Highlighting special cases?

As a starter, you can get a similar appearing chart using Excel's Bar (horizontal column) Chart.

[image: Bar]

If you're looking for the circular markers, you can modify an XY/Scatter Chart to accomplish the look (but matching the bar chart's info).

[image: XY Scatter Basic]

If you're looking for the more stylized infographic appearance, you can really tweak the XY/Scatter Chart and get the more complex appearance.

[image]

If you'll edit your question with additional direction, I can provide you with a more complete answer to meet your needs.

Comment: I was looking for the circular markers. I have something barely looking to your solution but not looking as good as you. I'm still interested to know how you made the background.